# When I run a text based game through python the text I am putting into the terminal when I run it turns yellow. When entering the text an error shows

Tags: python, multiple-choice, text-based, adventure

So I am very new to python. The text based game I'm making incorperates multiple choices and routes to choose from. I'd imagine I use the very basic ways of executing things, that's because I primarily use if/else/elif statements. The following is the problem I occur when presented the second question in the game from either of the two main routes.

[This is the full problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmfkd.png)

I assume this is a simple problem but I truly do not know. I used all if statements for the choices. The start of each choices starts like the following.

[This is showing example of code that I've used in my adventure game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oLKO.png)

I'd prefer a thorough explanation so that I may learn alongside fixing this error. To whoever may answer to my problem is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please inline text rather than posting or linking images of it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a print statement instead of an input statement for text that you want to enter. It gives you "yellow" text because you are entering commands in `powershell` and not in your program as it had already ended.

The program ended because it had nothing more to do. The variable `answer` didn't match any of the later `if` statements and thus moved to the end and terminated.

Instead of:

```
print("There is atleast a dozen of these nasty creatures. (Run or fight)")
```

Do:

```
answer = input("There is atleast a dozen of these nasty creatures. (Run or fight)")
```

Comment: Thank you, I seriously appreciate the help I can get with python. You have yourself a good day sir.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, then please feel free to mark it as the chosen answer. Thanks!